# Iterate through each integer python separated by a blankspace/endline

Tags: python-3.x, input

I am a Python 2.7 user who recently switched to python3. While reading integers separated by a blackspace/endline I used `nex = iter(map(int,stdin.read().split())).next`, where `nex()` acts as a function to input integers (Suppose for inputting an integral value in x -> `x=nex()`. But in python3 this doesn't seem to work. Someone please propose a workaround for using the same in Python3.

Comment: Note that `map` is already an iterator in Python 3. Consider reading the docs on the changes, particularly https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#operators-and-special-methods

Comment: you don't need to read all input, to get an iterator, see [How to read tokens without reading whole line or file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20019503/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.next()` method is called `.__next__()` in Python 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/). You could use `next()` *function* to write single-source Python 2/3 compatible code:

```
from functools import partial

nex = partial(next, iter(iterable))
print(nex())
```