# How to find floating point numbers in binary file with Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, binary, floating-point

I have a binary file mixed with ASCII in which there are some floating point numbers I want to find. The file contains some lines like this:

`1,1,'11.2','11.3';1,1,'100.4';`

In my favorite regex tester I found that the correct regex should be `([0-9]+\.{1}[0-9]+)`.

Here's the code:

```
import re

data = open('C:\\Users\\Me\\file.bin', 'rb')
pat = re.compile(b'([0-9]+\.{1}[0-9]+)')
print(pat.match(data.read()))
```

I do not get a single match, why is that? I'm on Python 3.5.1.

Comment: Are floats represented as strings?

Comment: Yes, they are ASCII encoded.

Comment: What is a *binary file mixed with ASCII* and how can you identify the ASCII and binary parts? Without knowing that I cannot tell you how you can safely read the file. BTW, you regex fails to match `1.`, `.5`, not speaking of `1` (but for this last part it may be desirable to fail)

Comment: @SergeBallesta Sorry I meant ASCII and non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
import re
with open('C:\\Users\\Me\\file.bin', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

re.findall("\d+\.\d+", data)
```

**Output**:

```
['11.2', '11.3', '100.4']
```

`re.findall` returns `string` list. If you want to convert to float you can do like this

```
>>> list(map(float, re.findall("\d+\.\d+", data)))
[11.2, 11.3, 100.4]
```

Comment: Not working, tells me `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`. It contains binary stuff.

Comment: @JohnnyFromBF you should try, `re.findall("\d+\.\d+", data.read())`

Comment: I'm afraid it still says `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`.

Comment: @JohnnyFromBF, why are you opening in binary mode?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham If I don't it says `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 313: character maps to <undefined>`.

Comment: @JohnnyFromBF,  are you sure it is not a latin-1 encoded file? What does the actual content look like? Try `encoding="latin-1"`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Turns out, the file was indeed in a wrong encoding m(

Comment: @AdemÖztaş: the question has Python 3 tag. `str` pattern won't work with `bytes` data.

Comment: @JohnnyFromBF .. It was better for the sake of good interpretation of the source of your issue to post that traceback message instead...This is called an [X-Y problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2):

> How to find floating point numbers in binary file with Python?

```
float_re = br"[+-]? *(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?"
for m in generate_tokens(r'C:\Users\Me\file.bin', float_re):
    print(float(m.group()))
```

where [`float_re` is from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/385597/4279) and [`generate_tokens()` is defined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20024735/4279).

---

`pat.match()` tries to match at the very start of the input string and your string does not start with a float and therefore you *"do not get a single match"*.

---

`re.findall("\d+\.\d+", data)` produces `TypeError` because the pattern is Unicode (`str`) but `data` is a `bytes` object in your case. Pass the pattern as `bytes`:
`re.findall(b"\d+\.\d+", data)`

Comment: Your pattern allows for a space after the leading sign character, which I believe is an error. For example, "- 2.2" is not a floating point number, but "-2.2" is.

Comment: Also, if you want to be really pedantic, you could limit the number of allowable exponent digits, if you knew whether this was a 32- or 64-bit floating-point value.

Comment: @SteveHollasch What is or is not a float is a matter of a definition. Follow the link that explains the origin of the regex.